# How to build only modified modules and dependencies in Gradle

Tags: java, git, gradle, gradle-plugin

I use [gitflow-incremental-builder](https://github.com/gitflow-incremental-builder/gitflow-incremental-builder#configuration) with Maven in a monorepo model. It allows me to:

- Build only these modules in feature branch that differ from main branch.
- Build only these modules that changed from last successful build tag.
- When a library changes, build all the modules that use it.
- Build a library if needed for modules, but if nothing changed, skip tests (`skipTestsForUpstreamModules`)
- Force build all.

Changes are resolved using git log and then it affects the reactor config.

I am looking for a similar tool that will do it for Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

[Gradle Build Cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html) will automatically track the inputs and outputs of tasks and will skip any that have not changed.

##### Enabling Gradle Build Cache

It can be enabled locally by adding in `gradle.properties`

```properties
org.gradle.caching=true
```

or by adding a flag to the command line

```shell
./gradlew tests --build-cache
```

##### Sharing the build cache

The build cache for a project [can be shared](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#sec:build_cache_setup_http_backend) across multiple machines over HTTP. Sharing the build cache remotely isn't necessary - it can still work, even if the cache is stored locally.

##### Register task inputs

Gradle needs to know about the all inputs and outputs of tasks, otherwise tasks might be skipped, so make sure they are correctly registered.

For example, if some integration tests depend on an environment variable, then register the environment variable as a test-task input.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

tasks.named("integrationTest") {
  // TEST_TASK_QUALITY is used in integration tests to change <blah blah blah>
  // register it as an input so Gradle knows when to re-run the tests
  inputs.property("TEST_TASK_QUALITY", providers.environmentVariable("TEST_TASK_QUALITY"))
}
```

##### Stable task outputs

Gradle will use the outputs of some tasks as the inputs of other tasks. If the outputs aren't stable, then Gradle will always re-run the dependent tasks.

For that reason, it's worth enabling [reproducible builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:reproducible_archives) in all projects.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

tasks.withType<AbstractArchiveTask>().configureEach {
    isPreserveFileTimestamps = false
    isReproducibleFileOrder = true
}
```

Also, consider [input normalization](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:configure_input_normalization) for any custom files your project has.

Comment: Thank you for a very comprehensive answer. I know the caching option, however, I'd like to not generate build output from unmodified modules (e.g. docker containers). Also, the remote cache requires a new piece of infrastructure to maintain.